# Redirecting a Stream to a Text Box in real-time

Tags: c#, winforms, console, textreader, textwriter

I have got an interesting dilemma where my application can run as a Console App or a Windows Forms App.

Since I do not want to write a shed load of code like this all over my application:

```
If ( IsConsoleApp() )
{
    // process Console input and output
}
else
{
    // process Windows input and output
}
```

To prevent this, I have decided to create two methods where I can pass in a TextReader and TextWriter instance and subsequently use these to process input and output, e.g.

```
public void SetOutputStream( TextWriter outputStream )
{
    _outputStream = outputStream;
}

public void SetInputStream( TextReader inputStream )
{
    _inputStream = inputStream;
}

// To use in a Console App:
SetOutputStream( Console.Out );
SetInputStream( Console.In );
```

To display some text in the Console window I just need to do something like this:

```
_outputStream.WriteLine( "Hello, World!");
```

And the text is magically redirected to the Console.

Now, my issue is how do I do something similar for a Windows application?  I have created a form with a read-only Text Box control on it and I want the contents of the `_outputStream` to be redirected to this text box in real-time.

Also, I want the `_inputStream` to contain the contents of another Text Box control so that my App can read from this stream instead of the Text Box directly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a reasonable design.  There aren't any streams built into the framework that connect directly to textboxes, but you can implement your own subclass pretty easily.  And there probably are some third-party solutions with lots of features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind Console Output to RichEdit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744668/bind-console-output-to-richedit)

Comment: @HansPassant I've taken a look at the link you provided and that is basically redirecting a console output to a Textbox, which isn't what I am looking for.  I am looking to attach a stream to a Textbox, so that any writes to the stream automatically appear in the Textbox.

Comment: And you haven't considered just using Console.Write/Line() in your code at all?  Very unclear why.  Clearly that will go the console in console mode.  And to a text box in GUI mode with the provided solution.

Comment: I have answered my own question and posted a solution should anyone require something like this.

Comment: Did you managed to really solve this in the end? A person commented on your answer saying it wouldn't work. I have a very similar problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this by creating a `ConcurrentStreamWriter` class that inherits `StreamWriter` and uses a `ConcurrentQueue` backed up by `BackgroundWorker` to process the queue's contents.

This is the solution I have come up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Quest.Core.IO
{
    public class ConcurrentStreamWriter : StreamWriter
    {
        private ConcurrentQueue<String> _stringQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<String>();
        private Boolean _disposing;
        private RichTextBox _textBox;

        public ConcurrentStreamWriter( Stream stream )
            : base( stream )
        {
            CreateQueueListener();
        }

        public ConcurrentStreamWriter( Stream stream, RichTextBox textBox )
            : this( stream )
        {
            _textBox = textBox;
        }

        public override void WriteLine()
        {
            base.WriteLine();
            _stringQueue.Enqueue( Environment.NewLine );
        }

        public override void WriteLine( string value )
        {
            base.WriteLine( value );
            _stringQueue.Enqueue( String.Format( "{0}\n", value ) );
        }

        public override void Write( string value )
        {
            base.Write( value );
            _stringQueue.Enqueue( value );
        }

        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            base.Dispose( disposing );

            _disposing = disposing;
        }

        private void CreateQueueListener()
        {
            var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

            bw.DoWork += ( sender, args ) =>
            {
                while ( !_disposing )
                {
                    if ( _stringQueue.Count > 0 )
                    {
                        string value = string.Empty;
                        if ( _stringQueue.TryDequeue( out value ) )
                        {
                            if ( _textBox != null )
                            {
                                if ( _textBox.InvokeRequired )
                                {
                                    _textBox.Invoke( new Action( () =>
                                    {
                                        _textBox.AppendText( value );
                                        _textBox.ScrollToCaret();
                                    } ) );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    _textBox.AppendText( value );
                                    _textBox.ScrollToCaret();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got here from the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18786802/69809), so now I can see the whole code. Yes, this won't work, as I've already mentioned there. `MemoryStream` is not thread-safe for sharing between threads. You should ditch the `StreamWriter`, replace `MemoryStream` with a `ConcurrentQueue<string>`, and use `Enqueue`/`Dequeue` to work with the FIFO buffer.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing like this built into the framework. Instead of doing it the hard way, simply add a static helper method (available anywhere) that you will call whenever you want to output something:

```
public static void Output(string message)
{
    if ( IsConsoleApp() )
    {
        // process Console input and output
    }
    else
    {
        // process Windows input and output
    }
}
```

Then just have one line when you want output to show:

```
Utils.Output("Hello, World!");
```

To identify whether running as Console or not, you can use such code:

```
private static bool? IsConsole = null;
public static void Output(string message)
{
    if (IsConsole == null)
    {
        int width;
        try
        {
            width = Console.WindowWidth;
        }
        catch
        {
            width = 0;
        }
        IsConsole = (width > 0);
    }

    if (IsConsole.Value == true)
    {
        // process Console input and output
    }
    else
    {
        // process Windows input and output
    }
}
```

Not super elegant, but should work.

Comment: The static method would then need to know whether the application is running as a console or Windows; that information is only available in a separate instance object containing the application's data.  Can a static method access instance data?

Comment: @MikeClarke see my edit for a way to identify this without needing anything else. :)

Comment: the only issue I can see is that the Windows portion of your code would not know which Form instance to use, which is why I wanted to use Streams in the first place.  My application's data has an enum that I use to determine whether the app is to run as a console or Windows, so I'd much rather use that.  It looks like I am going to have to rethink my design.

Comment: This depends how and where you store the form instance?