# Pause a BackgroundWorker for n-seconds

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, thread-sleep

I was feeling nostalgic and have developed a text based Adventure Game Creator IDE, which has a Windows Form that displays messages to a rich text box.

I have written a message dispatcher class that will send text (room descriptions and messages) from a stream to the text box using a BackgroundWorker.  This works brilliantly, but I am having a small problem...

I need to do is be able to pause/hold the Background worker for any number of seconds of my choosing.  The reason for this is that, in the adventure scripting language, there is a statement called `HOLD` which will pause the game for n-seconds.

The problem is that I am displaying a message using the message dispatcher (The snake comes over and bites you and you die....), but the HOLD statement is being executed BEFORE the message gets displayed.  This is no good for me as I require the message to be displayed FIRST and then pause the game.

In the execution context for the HOLD method I have got:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Join( _value * 10 );
```

I have also tried:

```
Thread.Sleep( _value * 10 );
```

Neither of these work, so I am asking whether it is possible to pause the BackgroundWorker for any number of seconds?

** EDIT **

Added the code for the `BackgroundWorker`:

```
public delegate void OnReceiveData( object sender, StreamWatcherEventArgs e );

public class StreamWatcher
{
    public event OnReceiveData DataReceived = delegate { };

    private Stream _stream;

    public StreamWatcher( Stream stream )
    {
        _stream = stream;

        CreateWatcherThread();
    }

    private void CreateWatcherThread()
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += ( sender, args ) =>
        {
            while ( true )
            {
                if ( _stream.Length > 0 )
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Join( 50 );

                    byte[] buf = new byte[ _stream.Length ];

                    _stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
                    _stream.Read( buf, 0, buf.Length );

                    string data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString( buf );

                    DataReceived( this, new StreamWatcherEventArgs( data ) );

                    _stream.SetLength( 0 );
                }
            }
        };

        bw.RunWorkerAsync(); ;

    }

}
```

Just for interest this is the script being executed:

```
IF ( VERB(7) AND NOUN(5) ) MESSLF(14) HOLD(200) EXIT END
```

This basically says if I type "GET SNAKE" it will display a message to the text box via the message dispatcher and then pause the game for 2 seconds.

The problem is the pause occurs first BEFORE the message is displayed, because the pause is occurring on the main thread.

Here is the `DataReceived` event handler:

```
_watcher.DataReceived += ( s, e ) =>
{
    if ( rtbOutput.InvokeRequired )
    {
        rtbOutput.Invoke( new Action( () =>
        {
            rtbOutput.AppendText( e.Data );
            rtbOutput.ScrollToCaret();
        } ) );
    }
    else
    {
        rtbOutput.AppendText( e.Data );
        rtbOutput.ScrollToCaret();
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the code of the `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: Updated my post with the `BackgroundWorker` code.

Comment: I have a feeling that `DataReceived` is where all the magic happens? Where did you call the `Thread.Sleep` method?

Comment: Have you tried move the sleep at the end of if?

Comment: I am calling the `Thread.Sleep` from the Hold statement method in the Abstract Syntax Tree.  It uses the visitor pattern to execute the statements as they occur.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria the `Sleep(50)` method you see is not the one causing the problem.  That is for an entirely different reason so moving it will not change anything.  The problem is the `Thread.Sleep` is being called within the Abstract Syntax Tree meaning I have a main thread (where the Sleep is occurring) and the `BackgroundWorker` where the message is being displayed.  I need to pause the `BackgroundWorker` instead of doing a `Thread.Sleep` in the AST,.

Comment: Added further updates to my post to describe the issue more clearly.

Comment: Well, without posting the code, you may as well have a new thread being created inside your `DataReceived` handler and have everything running nondeterministically. The only problem with this part of your code is the unnecessary `Thread.Join` (i.e. `Thread.Sleep`), which only indicates a potential race condition. Pausing threads just to ensure that you've received certain amount of data is a bad practice.

Comment: @Groo the reason for the `Thread.CurrentThread.Join( 50 );` is to ensure the message dispatcher is able to pump out the messages from the stream to the text box correctly.  Taking this line out will cause a lot of messages not to display so it acts as a 'choke' to slow things down a bit.  The `DataReceived` handler is basically just doing a `TextBox.Invoke(...)` to append the text to the text box.

Comment: I don't see the reasoning behind that. If your input stream is producing data at a certain speed, throttling the consumer only means that your producer queue will overfill.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't make any sense. Now you've added the code for appending text to a text box.

Comment: There is no queue here.  I basically writing text to a thread, for which the `BackgroundWorker` does some polling on the stream before raising the `DataReceived` event passing the stream contents to the caller.  If I took the sleep out it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.

Comment: What's filling the stream? I don't think anyone filling the stream would like someone else doing a `Seek` to the beginning in the middle of writing to it. By adding the delay you are (hopefully, if the other thread doesn't get delayed) allowing the producer to end writing to it. You should simply use a [`ConcurrentQueue<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) to exchange textual messages between 1 producer and 1 consumer.

Comment: I see a call to `Stream.Seek` in your code. Which executes on a background thread. Meaning you are moving the cursor on a `Stream` shared between two threads. And I understand that this part has nothing to do with your actual problem, but you still haven't posted the relevant code, or at least the skeleton of the part where messages are parsed and executed, so this is the only mistake that I can see.

Comment: The reason for the `Stream.Seek` is to put the stream at the beginning to receive the next stream input.  I will give your suggestion of using a concurrent queue some thought, but I am not sure how it'll work on a stream as I would need to queue the stream contents.

Comment: Simply put, a `Stream` is not appropriate for sharing data between threads, while a data structure like `ConcurrentQueue` is. One thread can call `queue.Enqueue`, the other one can check the `Count` and call `Dequeue` in a thread-safe manner. Calling `Stream.Seek` while a different thread is writing data to it will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: The reason I am using a `Stream` is because my application can run either as a Windows or Console application.  For a Console application I simply pass `Console.Out` as the stream for displaying text to the console WITHOUT having to do a `Console.Write(...)` which will not work in a Windows application.  I don't want to put `If ( IsConsoleApp() )` all over my application so I decided that using a Stream would be the best way of making the application work for both mediums.  If you know of a way of sending text to the console or a text box without using a load of If statements then I'm all ears

Comment: Ok, I am not near my PC right now, so I'll probably have more time later. One more thing you still haven't shown is: when does the actual processing happen? Is that a separate event handler attached to the `StreamWatcher`? At least set a breakpoint at your "HOLD" `Thread.Sleep` and show the stack trace in the debugger, that's the execution path which is important for solving your initial issue.